# Reading Average from with SQL Query in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, average

I need to run a SQL Query in vb.net to find the average rating for my application. I think this is the correct SQL for doing this:

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM Feedback;
```

The only problem is im not sure how to run this query correctly. I had a similar query which I have changed to the following(It doesnt work) and I just wondered if you could help adapt this so it actually works?

```
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(DBCred)
    Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM Feedback;"
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim AVGRating As String
    conn.Close()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Try
        AVGRating = cmd.r
    Finally
        cmd.Connection.Close()

    End Try
    conn.Close()
```

thanks
Chris

Comment: If I remember correctly, you may need to add an alias: `SELECT AVG(Rating) AS rating ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
    Dim AVGRating As String = String.Empty
    Using xConn As New MySqlConnection(DBCred)
        Using xComm As New MySqlCommand()
            With xComm
                .Connection = xConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM Feedback WHERE Feedback.Rating > 0"
            End With
            Try
                xConn.Open()
                AVGRating = CStr(xComm.ExecuteScalar)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                xConn.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

**[Link: ADO.NET ExecuteScalar in SqlCommand Object](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-executescalar-sqlcommand.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to Execute the command - in this instance, use `ExecuteScalar`

```
AVGRating = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```